How can i install MSSQL SERVER on Ubuntu 24
I have been looking for a way to install an SQL server on Ubuntu 24 but I cannot find any.

There are many SQL servers, you didn't mention which one do you want. However, your topic says "MSSQL", so I guess you want to install Microsoft SQL Server. Here is a Microsoft guide on how to install it, maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver16

This question is similar to: How do I install MSSQL Server and/or Tools for Linux on 16.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
